# Angular JS : Disable Input Box is not sustained on page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have an Input box that accepts characters  which gets disable instantly when the correct value is entered using ng-disabled

However when I move to the next item and prev the next button the page refreshes

= 4) &&

I need to be able to place the index of the question into Cache

localStorage.setItem();

Controller:

```js
$scope.initializeGame = function() {

    $scope.score = (localStorage.getItem("token")) ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token")) : 0;
    $scope.scoreValue = $scope.score
    $scope.noOfTries = 0;
    $scope.original = $scope.pageTitle;
    $scope.guess = null;
    $scope.deviation = null;

    $scope.verifyGuess = function() {
        $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;

        $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
        $scope.falseAnswer = $scope.deviation != 0;
        if ($scope.deviation == 0 && $scope.noOfTries == 1) {

          $scope.scoreValue = parseInt($scope.score, 10) + 1;
          var token = $scope.scoreValue;

          localStorage.setItem("token", token);

};
```

Comment: do you not see the item in localStorage?

Comment: I was more after the method of from a returned list objects from an ng-repeat statement  how do I record using the index number of the object that it has been answered correctly    e.g.   into local Storage or any other method to sustain that it has been answered.

Comment: are you using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)? because if you were before the next page was resolved, you could call a function to check if the next expected id was answered in your local and then if so, set it.

Answer (score 1):

From your html, pass `$index` to the method being called. This will give you the index of the particular question for which the method is called.